# Restoring SQL Server database using just the MDF file without LDF

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-restore

I have SQL Server 2008 R2, and I need to restore my database to another server but `backup.ldf` file has been corrupted, so is it possible to restore my database using just the `.mdf` file alone? Or is there any possibilities for creating the `.ldf` file manually?

Comment: Good question. I would like to know the answer myself! Why not try it out? Copy the `.mdf` into the data directory of your MSSQL server and connect it in SSMS. As far as I understand it the `.ldf` file holds information relating to open transactions. So this information will not be available when you set up the new database. -- OK, I think @Alex K. 's solution is to be preferred! ;-)

Comment: YMMV sp_attach_single_file_db

Comment: i tried USE [master]
GO
-- Method 1: I use this method
EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname='TestDb',
@physname=N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TestDb.mdf'
GO

Answer (score 1):

You can try `attaching` the MDF by right clicking on databases in SSMS, and deleting the reference to the log file location in that dialog, and a new one will be created, assuming the MDF is not corrupt.

Comment: I already tried by removing the ldf file,but File activation failure. The physical file name "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DCFHO_log.ldf" may be incorrect.
The log cannot be rebuilt because there were open transactions/users when the database was shutdown, no checkpoint occurred to the database, or the database was read-only. This error could occur if the transaction log file was manually deleted or lost due to a hardware or environment failure.
Msg 1813, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Could not open new database 'TestDb'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.

Comment: its possible to recreate ldf file